# ネストされた辞書のリストからデータフレームを作成するには？

Tags: python, pandas

下記のようなネストされた辞書のリストから最終的にデータフレームを作成したいと考えています。

辞書がネストされているため、このままpandasで `df = pd.DataFrame(sample)` としてデータフレームを作成しても列が'Tdnet'のデータフレームが作成されてしまいます。

目標としてcolumnsが'id', 'pubdate', 'company_code'...となるようなデータフレームを作成したいのですが、何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

初心者のため、分かりやすく教えていただけますと嬉しいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

---

**辞書リストの例:**

```py
print(sample)
[{'Tdnet': {'company_code': '60310',
   'company_name': 'Ｍ－サイジニア',
   'document_url': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/091220210813486467.zip',
   'id': '795467',
   'markets_string': '東',
   'pubdate': '2021-08-13 18:30:00',
   'title': '個別業績の前年実績値との差異に関するお知らせ',
   'update_history': None,
   'url_report_type_earnings_forecast': None,
   'url_report_type_expected_dividends': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_non_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_summary': None,
   'url_xbrl': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/091220210813486467.zip'}},
 {'Tdnet': {'company_code': '70570',
   'company_name': 'Ｊ－エヌ・シー・エヌ',
   'document_url': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/081220210813486323.zip',
   'id': '795470',
   'markets_string': '東',
   'pubdate': '2021-08-13 18:20:00',
   'title': '2022年3月期第1四半期決算短信［日本基準］（連結）',
   'update_history': None,
   'url_report_type_earnings_forecast': None,
   'url_report_type_expected_dividends': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_non_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_summary': None,
   'url_xbrl': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/081220210813486323.zip'}},
 {'Tdnet': {'company_code': '24670',
   'company_name': 'バルクＨＤ',
   'document_url': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/081220210813486440.zip',
   'id': '795458',
   'markets_string': '名',
   'pubdate': '2021-08-13 18:00:00',
   'title': '2022年３月期 第１四半期決算短信〔日本基準〕（連結）',
   'update_history': None,
   'url_report_type_earnings_forecast': None,
   'url_report_type_expected_dividends': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_fs_non_consolidated': None,
   'url_report_type_summary': None,
   'url_xbrl': 'https://webapi.yanoshin.jp/rd.php?https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/081220210813486440.zip'}}]
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda d: d['Tdnet'], sample))`

Comment: ありがとうございます！for文など使わわずにできるものなのですね...。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(解決してるようですが … とりあえず回答として)

すべてのデータが `'Tdnet'` で纏まっているようなので, 次のようにできます

```py
import pandas as pd
lst = [d['Tdnet']for d in sample]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
display(df)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！最初for文でやってみたのですが、変に複雑にしてしまって…。勉強になりました！